# How to put a hyperlink in the middle of a paragraph using the slim templating language?

Tags: ruby, templates, slim-lang

How do you write the following in the [slim](http://slim-lang.com/) templating language?

```
<p>Join the <a href="">Google group</a> and let us know what you think, or what other features you’d like to see.</p>
```

I tried the following:

```
p
  ' Join the
  a href="" Google Group
  ' and let us know what you think, or what other features you’d like to see
```

But that doesn't work because the words 'Group' and 'and' do not have whitespace between them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently you can add extra spaces after the quote:

```
p
  ' Join the
  a href="" Google Group
  '  and let us know what you think, or what other features you’d like to see
```

Comment: This is correct. The space after the quote becomes your left margin. You're free to add as many spaces as you like to the beginning of the line.

Comment: This syntax makes me want to vomit a little bit.

Comment: Whoa, let's go with the other answer.

Comment: but this doesn't manage to get a space between "the" and "Google".  I still can't figure this out.

Comment: To add leading/trailing spaces around the tag use the `<` and `>` characters after the `a`.  See the [Slim Docs](https://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames#trailing-and-leading-whitespace) for details. Also, for the vomiters, you can use `= link_to 'Google Group', '#'` instead of the anchor tag.  It is a bit less nauseous.

Answer (score 10):

You can do

```
 p This is a paragraph with a link #{link_to 'embedded', 'http://google.com'}.
```

Rails tag helpers are just methods, so you can apply that logic to other methods inside views.